# how to add signature to a DDL trigger?

Tags: sql-server, ddl-trigger

I have a DDL trigger on a database. I want to add a signature to it, by certificate. I have full sa rights, but when I try to run the statement

```
ADD SIGNATURE TO OBJECT::[objects_monitoring]
BY CERTIFICATE [mail_certificate] 
WITH PASSWORD = 'password1';
GO
```

I get the following error

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot alter the object 'objects_monitoring', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

How do I go about adding the signature to this DDL trigger?

Comment: I suspect that you need to use a different module_class than `OBJECT`, but there's not a great deal of documentation around on what other module_class values are supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsecurity/thread/1333eecd-4c66-43d4-ab8f-03511cad4174), DDL triggers cannot be signed.